# Change maxFractionDigit of JXL cell

Tags: java, jxl

I am using JXL API to read excel. Now I am facing an issue: whenever there is a number with more than 3 decimal places (like .2014,2.23456) inside excel, while I am reading the value from the cell of excel it is returning only 3 decimal places (like .201, 2.234). While I check I found that the cell (JXL api) have a property named "maxFractionDigit" as 3 and that's why it is reading only 3 decimal places. Can anyone tell me how to change this property value.

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got something and this is working:

((NumberCell)cell).getValue()

This returns Double value and all the precisions.